# Pylint error with abstract member variable

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def random_function(self):
        print self.name

    def abstract_function(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("This is an abstract class")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def abstract_function(self):
        print "This is not an abstract class"
```

Pylint reports error:

> ID:E1101 A.random_function: Instance of 'A' has no 'name' member

It's true, but I don't care because A is abstract.  Is there a way to get rid of this warning without just suppressing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is best to define `name` in A. Consider somebody (or you in couple weeks) wants to inherit from A and implements `abstract_function`:

```
class C(A):
    def abstract_function(self):
        print 'This is not an abstract class'
```

Now the following will raise an error even though nothing in C seems to be wrong:

```
c = C()
c.random_function()
```

If you are using `self.name` in A it should be defined there (and let's say it should default to something sensible saying it's not ready to use):

```
class A(object):
    name = None
    def random_function(self):
        print self.name
```

This will make your code cleaner/less error-prone and you will also get rid of the pylint error.

Answer (score 5):

If you suffix A with `Mixin`, pylint will not report it

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd could use the following option:

```
pylint solution.py --generated-members=name
```

However, it's better to consider adding `name = None` to the base class.